# How can we make a particular value in sql row display its value on html table row and its updated value in next row in that table using php?

Tags: php, sql

For Example,

Let us take in an **`sql`** table we have following things in a row:

- username
- password
- payment amount

I have a form where I can type an amount to store in database and also it is stored in html table. when I type a different amount then it should be stored and new row should be added with this updated value in that table.

How to achieve this using **`php`**?

Comment: Do you want to make a grid for all users?

Comment: Whenever i give an input in an inputbox it should be stored in sql table and displayed on html table. again if i change the input in inputbox, new row should be added in that html table. Yes i want it for all users

Comment: how about this http://jsfiddle.net/urpbv4n1/  ? 
You can make an AJAX call on SAVE action and in it check in php that if new payment has arrived then insert row

Comment: Thank u for solution

Answer (score 0):

You need to create this via ajax.

1. Add ajax script with loop update every `n` sec.
2. Create php page with content.

Call ajax every second and append result with message to div `.js_messages`.

**HTML page with ajax:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="js_messages"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function updateMessage() {
            var $messageContainer = $('.js_messages');

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "test.php",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data){
                    $messageContainer.append('<div class="js_messages-item">' + data.message + '</div>')
                },
            });
        }

        window.setInterval(function(){
          updateMessage()
        }, 1000);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP page:**

Just generate random message for example.

```
<?php

echo json_encode(['message' => mt_rand()]);
```

Comment: I am not that good at ajax can  u help with that ajax script.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Thank u so much zen